# Create a vertex buffer with a variant size

Tags: directx-11

I want to create a vertex buffer with variant size for desc.ByteWidth as shown in the following. How to do this?
Thanks a lot.

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory( &desc, sizeof( desc ) );`enter code here`
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
desc.ByteWidth = size;//make it variant
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
d3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &desc, initialVertexData, &vertexBuffer );
```

Comment: Please clearly explain the problem you are having. What did you expect and what happened? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer  size and description in DirectX11 are fixed on creation time, that means if you need to update any of those parameters (size/usage) , you need to release this buffer and create a new one.

However, if you want to upload dynamic amount of data, you can create a buffer "big enough" , and only upload part of it ( as your buffer is dynamic, you do it via the [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

It is totally allowed to fill only a small part of this, and then use a draw function that only uses a subset of the data.

For example, using the [Draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476407(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

If you buffer size is for 32 vertices, you can still use:

```
 devicecontext.Draw(5, 0);
```

This will only draw the first 5 vertices, regardless of the total size.